# Как использовать прокси с библиотекой

Tags: proxy, instagram

Есть рабочий прокси
Есть библиотека - instaloader
Как мне сделать так, чтобы библиотека использовала этот прокси?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import instaloader
from instaloader import Profile, Post

proxies = {
 'https':f'http://666.666.666.666:666'
 }



def get_location(url):
 #Тут я проверяю работоспособность прокси и он 100%
 response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers,proxies=proxies)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
 ip = soup.find('div', class_ ='ip').text.strip()
 location = soup.find('div' ,class_='value-country').text.strip()
 print(f'IP:{ip}\nLocation:{location}')

def main():
 get_location(url=f'https://2ip.ru/')
 #Тут я начинаю работать с библиотекой
 instance = instaloader.Instaloader()
 post = Post.from_shortcode(instance.context, "CkCxYKajJTM")
 instance.download_post(post, target="folderName")


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Comment: А вы документацию пробовали глянуть или это не наш метод?

Comment: Ждал пока мне Владимир Клыков объяснит

Comment: Ну нет так нет, я помочь хотел, даже проверил есть ли это в доках на либу :)